# Passing which button was clicked to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'd like to be able to pass just the model to a controller method. However, there is more than one button on this form. There doesn't seem to be a way to let the controller know which button was clicked unless you also pass the FormCollection values.

In this particular case (having more than one submit button on the form), what would be the syntax of the Html.Beginform and Ajax.BeginForm objects in order to pass these values.

I know the controller name, action method, model, and formcollection would be on the BeginForm, but I don't know the syntax.

Instead of the formcollection values, I guess I could have a hiddenfield value signifying which button was clicked --- correct?

Anyway, if someone could supply the syntax for the methods, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do is probably the hidden field for the button press.

It would look something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.ButtonPressed, new { @id = "hidden_button_pressed_id"})
     <button id='blueButton'>Blue Button</button>
     <button id='redButton'>Red Button</button>
     <button type='submit'>Submit Form</button>
}
```

Then using jquery (not required)

```
$(function() {
    $('#blueButton').click(function() {
        $('#hidden_button_pressed_id').val('blueButton');
    }
    $('#redButton').click(function() {
        $('#hidden_button_pressed_id').val('redButton');
    }
}
```

Now when your form is submitted the `ButtonPressed` property will contain 'blueButton' if the blue button was pressed, or 'redButton' if the red button was pressed.  I'm not sure what your model looks like so I this is obviously just an example you'll have to change to suit your needs, but hopefully gets you started.

Comment: I see... I'll change the variable id to buttonPressed which would then set the value to the ButtonPressed property in my ViewModel. Thanks a lot! I appreciate it...